# Why Is There Errors on forgeSample When I Copied And Pasted The Section As-Is?

Tags: autodesk-forge

On this page:
[OAuthController.cs](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/2legged/net)

I added the section of code from the page.  However I get the following errors:

I removed the reference to my personal location and changed it to mine.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: forgeSample, Configuration: Debug Any
>   CPU ------
>   1>C:\Users\mine\source\repos\forgeSample\forgeSample\Controllers\forgeSampleController.cs(1,7,1,15):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Autodesk' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\mine\source\repos\forgeSample\forgeSample\Controllers\OSSController.cs(1,7,1,15):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Autodesk' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\mine\source\repos\forgeSample\forgeSample\Controllers\OSSController.cs(2,7,2,15):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Autodesk' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>C:\Users\mine\source\repos\forgeSample\forgeSample\Controllers\forgeSampleController.cs(50,65,50,70):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Scope' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I was going along fine until this point.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the `Autodesk.Forge` Nuget Package as stated in the initial [Create a server](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/netcore_2legged) step, as it seems your IDE cannot find the Autodesk namespace.